# UIscrollview and drag and drop

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, drag-and-drop

I'm creating a kind of grid view where you can add some widgets inside of it and organise them as you want by drag and drop to rearrange them.
My grid view for now is a UIscroll view and the widgets are subclass of UIview.

Here is an example of grid you can have with that 
When I drag a widget I wanna be able to make the scroll view go down if the widget is near the bottom of the screen.
For now, my widgets have a UIPanGestureRecognizer
And the following code :

```
 func enterDragMode(recognizer:UIPanGestureRecognizer) {

    if (recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerState.Ended) || (recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerState.Cancelled) {
        gridNotificationCenter.postNotificationName("WidgetDragEnded", object: self)
        // Notify the grid and drop the widget here
    } else {
        var translation  = recognizer.translationInView(self.superview!)
        var newPoint = self.center
        newPoint.x += translation.x
        newPoint.y += translation.y

        if (CGRectContainsRect(moveDownRect, self.frame)) {
            var scrollview = self.superview as? UIScrollView
            if (scrollview != nil) {
              // need to find correct visible rect here 
              res!.scrollRectToVisible(visibleRect, animated: true)
            }
        }
        recognizer.setTranslation(CGPointZero, inView: self.superview)
    }
}
```

But i feel like I'm not using the right class to handle this properly since the callback is not triggered when I'm simply holding the view and not moving it. Is there a better way ?

Comment: This screams of ui collection view to me. Since it is a subclass of uiscrollview it will have the same properties with the added benefit of layouts. Anyway I assume that this code is in the widget class? Where has moveDownRect come from?

Comment: Move downRect is a constant rec inside of the widgetview, and yeah this code is from widget view. I didn't used a collectionview since all the widget may not have the same size a can also resize themselves.

Comment: And are you setting the content size for the scroll view larger than its frame? Is it hitting the set content offset code?

Comment: I'm not sure to get what you mean ?

Comment: If you set a break point on the line scrollview!.setContentOffset(contentOffset, animated: true) does it stop there? For scroll views to scroll they need a content size that is bigger than its frame.. you used to have to do that in code i.e scrollview setcontentSize: you can do it now in interface builder I think with auto layout

Comment: Yep it stop there, after a few research i need to use this instead :  res!.scrollRectToVisible(visibleRect, animated: true) (Gonna edit my post for that, but Anas10 answered my first question)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to set a virtual area near the bottom of your view. 
Trigger when the pan gesture is moved. If it enters the area, starts scrolling down as long as the pan gesture does not leave the area and does not end.

And use a timer (NSTimer not CADisplayLink because you can't apply a scroll on the view while you refresh it) to increase the size of your scrollview as long as you are in the specified area.